# Getting list of user-modified system files within subtree

Tags: linux, apt

Say that I know, that I updated some files in `/etc/pam.d` Can someone recommend command to get list of all files which differs from their last repository version? I used to have it, but cannot find it anywhere.

And while at it, can someone recommend a command to get diff of specific file without excessive downloading of debs?

Comment: May be too late for your problem, but you might consider using [etckeeper](https://github.com/wertarbyte/etckeeper) to keep track of changes in the future.

Comment: nice, didn't know about it, too late indeed, but installed for future. How do you tackle other configuration files on your machine? Keyboard config files are in /usr/share/X11/xkb/..., cinnamon(and other config files) in /usr as well ...

Comment: I largely deal with hundreds of servers and a few dozen desktops. On that scale, I keep as many configuration changes as possible in Puppet (substitute Ansible or Chef if you prefer) and have a standard config across many systems. With the Puppet configs kept under git control, revisions are fairly easy. And, since all of the systems come under one umbrella, we don't often have the problem of "it works for me but not for her". We have `etckeeper` installed on all systems just in case any particular system needs a configuration change that is not handled by Puppet.